# Ember.js: How to access JSON API metadata from store.findRecord call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am currently trying to figure out how to access metadata when using the `store.findRecord()` call.

In the guides (http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/handling-metadata/) it says that metadata can be accessed by doing the following:

```
store.query('post').then((result) => {
  let meta = result.get('meta');
})
```

I was hoping this would work when using `findRecord` as well

```
store.findRecord('book', params.id, {adapterOptions: {query: params}}).then((result) => {
    let meta = result.get('meta');
})
```

However this always returns undefined for the `meta` property.  I'm assuming that metadata is not being set when using `findRecord`.  I am returning valid JSON-API with a `meta` property at the top level like this:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "page": {
      "number": 1,
      "size": 100,
      "total": 20
    },
   "data":[
       // data here
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to access the metadata returned by the server when using findRecord() and the JSONAPISerializer and JSONAPIAdapters?

Thank you!

I am using the following versions:

```
Ember             : 2.1.0
Ember Data        : 2.1.0
jQuery            : 1.11.3
```

Comment: Is the record already present in the store when you're doing the findRecord?

Comment: Good thought but it's not already present in the store.  I also checked to make sure in the chrome inspector that the network request is being made and it is.  I'm starting to think this is just not supported right now.  Based on some discussions in slack it seems like the meta key only works on collections.

Comment: Take a look at the Ember Guides on `query` vs `queryRecord` vs `findRecord` etc. I think what you're trying to do with `findRecord` isn't possible:

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/finding-records/

Comment: @vikram7 Yes, I think findRecord doesn't support metadata out of the box.  I'm curious as to whether or not there is a workaround.

Comment: You could override the serializer

Comment: I may be late here, but... I don't know ember data well, but it seems like, even if it did expose the metadata with findRecord, it would expose the metadata from inside the resource object (i.e. within `"data"`) rather than from the top-level, right?

Answer (score 2):

metadata are not supported per-record basis, you can count of having them available if you use `store.query()` or when fetching relationships.
Quoting:

> For now, Ember Data only understands a top level meta object on queries and relationships (through related links).

Take a look at the following github [thread](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3419) for more information.

Comment: FYI I posted here on a way you can accomplish this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514055/how-to-access-top-level-meta-key-from-json-api-servers-200-response-when-callin/38312846#38312846