# How to access top level meta key from json-api server's 200 response when calling ember data's destroyRecord()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I'm working on an Ember app that is using Ember Data and the now default json-api adapter.

According to the json-api spec (http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-deleting) when deleting a record your server should return a `200` response if the deletion is successful and the server responds with just a top level `meta` key.

My current server does just this and I'm trying to figure out how to access the data in the top level meta object when using Ember Data's `model.destroyRecord()` method.

```
myModel.destroyRecord().then(function(model){
    // the returned value is the model.  How can I get the actual metadata 
    // returned by the server?   
});
```

The server response contains information about what exactly was deleted and looks like this:

```
{
   "meta": {
      num-deleted-a: 10,
      num-deleted-b: 100,
      num-deleted-c: 200
    }
}
```

I'd like to get this information so I can display it to the user.

Thank you!

I am using the following versions:

```
Ember             : 2.2.0
Ember Data        : 2.3.3
jQuery            : 1.11.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember does not support `meta` for single model requests (`find`,`save` and `destroyRecord`) at the moment!

If you want this you have to hook into ember internals.

**The following code uses ember internals from ember 2.3 and may break in future versions!**

There is the undocumented `_metadataFor` function on the `store` that gives you the last metadata for a given type. I use a custom initializer to always save it to the `Model`:

```
import Ember from 'ember'; 
import DS from 'ember-data';
const {set} = Ember;
export function initialize(application) {
  DS.Model.reopen({
    meta: null,
    didCommit() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      set(this, 'meta', this.store._metadataFor(this.constructor.modelName));
    }
  });
};

export default {
  name: 'meta',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

After this you can do `model.save().then(() => console.log(model.get('meta')))` or `model.destroyRecord.then(() => console.log(model.get('meta')))`.

[Maybe checkout this ember-twiddle.](https://ember-twiddle.com/d90a335bb2ad52813402?numColumns=1&openFiles=application.controller.js%2C)

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply! I stumbled across the `_metadataFor` property when tracing through the code and was able to use that.  I like how you added it directly into the model though.

Comment: Just FYI to folks coming to this that are using Ember 2.6.  This no longer appears to work.

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading to Ember 2.6.1 and Ember 2.6.1 I was no longer able to access the `store._metadataFor` property.

To get access to the metadata from a particular call I now override the serializer for the model and add a `meta` property to the model itself that simply passes through the metadata.

As an example I have a record type called `vote` which when saved returns some metadata.

For the model I do the following:

```
// Vote Model (/app/models/vote)
export default DS.Model.extend({
  vote: DS.attr('number'),
  // Since i don't provide a transform the values for meta are passed through in
  // raw form
  meta: DS.attr()
});
```

Then in the serializer for the vote model I do the following:

```
// Vote serializer (/app/serializers/vote)
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  normalizeSaveResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    // The metadata in the payload does get processed by default and will be
    // placed into a top level `meta` key on the returned documentHash
    let documentHash = this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);

    // Make sure we always have an empty object assigned to the meta attribute
    if(typeof(payload.meta) !== 'object'){
      payload.meta = {};
    }

    // Move the metadata into the attributes hash for the model
    documentHash.data.attributes.meta = payload.meta;

    return documentHash;
  }
});
```

Note that in the above example I'm only adding in metadata to the vote model when making a save call to the store.  If you wanted to always add in the metadata then you would override the `normalize` method instead of the `normalizeSaveResponse` method.

Then you can access a `meta` field in the results of your save call.

```
let vote = self.store.createRecord('vote', {
   vote: voteValue
});

vote.save().then(function(result){
   // this will now contain your metadata
   console.info(result.get('meta'));
});
```

Comment: normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {  
    payload.data.attributes.meta = payload.meta || {};
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments); 
}
// See: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers